# Printing several tibbles, in total taller than terminal, without losing the overreaching part

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble

Calling `print(tibblevariable)` by default only prints a few of its rows. This can be changed by setting `tibble.print_min` to a higher value.

Even when adjusting the minimum number of rows to print, I can't get more rows than how many can fit in my terminal window. Scrolling up after trying to do this just shows my earlier terminal input and output.

The situation I'm asking about may or may not be controlled in the same way. if I run `print(tibblevariable)` four times, and each `tibblevariable` is a tibble with 10 rows. and my terminal window is 24 characters tall, I will only see the last 24 rows of the output I asked for.

My question is **how I can get R to just print everything I ask it to without cutting it off when it extends beyond the window**.

I'm using the vim plugin Nvim-R, if that's relevant for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the print function with n as an argument

```
print(tibblevariable,n = Inf)
```

Pray this doesn't break anything on memory

Added reprex as proof

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% 
  tibble() %>%
  print(n = Inf)
#> # A tibble: 150 x 5
#>     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   
#>            <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>     
#>   1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa    
#>   2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa    
#>   3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa    
#>   4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa    
#>   5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa    
#>   6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa    
#>   7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa    
#>   8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa    
#>   9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa    
#>  10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa    
#>  11          5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2 setosa    
#>  12          4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2 setosa    
#>  13          4.8         3            1.4         0.1 setosa    
#>  14          4.3         3            1.1         0.1 setosa    
#>  15          5.8         4            1.2         0.2 setosa    
#>  16          5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4 setosa    
#>  17          5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4 setosa    
#>  18          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.3 setosa    
#>  19          5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3 setosa    
#>  20          5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3 setosa    
#>  21          5.4         3.4          1.7         0.2 setosa    
#>  22          5.1         3.7          1.5         0.4 setosa    
#>  23          4.6         3.6          1           0.2 setosa    
#>  24          5.1         3.3          1.7         0.5 setosa    
#>  25          4.8         3.4          1.9         0.2 setosa    
#>  26          5           3            1.6         0.2 setosa    
#>  27          5           3.4          1.6         0.4 setosa    
#>  28          5.2         3.5          1.5         0.2 setosa    
#>  29          5.2         3.4          1.4         0.2 setosa    
#>  30          4.7         3.2          1.6         0.2 setosa    
#>  31          4.8         3.1          1.6         0.2 setosa    
#>  32          5.4         3.4          1.5         0.4 setosa    
#>  33          5.2         4.1          1.5         0.1 setosa    
#>  34          5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2 setosa    
#>  35          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa    
#>  36          5           3.2          1.2         0.2 setosa    
#>  37          5.5         3.5          1.3         0.2 setosa    
#>  38          4.9         3.6          1.4         0.1 setosa    
#>  39          4.4         3            1.3         0.2 setosa    
#>  40          5.1         3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa    
#>  41          5           3.5          1.3         0.3 setosa    
#>  42          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3 setosa    
#>  43          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa    
#>  44          5           3.5          1.6         0.6 setosa    
#>  45          5.1         3.8          1.9         0.4 setosa    
#>  46          4.8         3            1.4         0.3 setosa    
#>  47          5.1         3.8          1.6         0.2 setosa    
#>  48          4.6         3.2          1.4         0.2 setosa    
#>  49          5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2 setosa    
#>  50          5           3.3          1.4         0.2 setosa    
#>  51          7           3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
#>  52          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
#>  53          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
#>  54          5.5         2.3          4           1.3 versicolor
#>  55          6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor
#>  56          5.7         2.8          4.5         1.3 versicolor
#>  57          6.3         3.3          4.7         1.6 versicolor
#>  58          4.9         2.4          3.3         1   versicolor
#>  59          6.6         2.9          4.6         1.3 versicolor
#>  60          5.2         2.7          3.9         1.4 versicolor
#>  61          5           2            3.5         1   versicolor
#>  62          5.9         3            4.2         1.5 versicolor
#>  63          6           2.2          4           1   versicolor
#>  64          6.1         2.9          4.7         1.4 versicolor
#>  65          5.6         2.9          3.6         1.3 versicolor
#>  66          6.7         3.1          4.4         1.4 versicolor
#>  67          5.6         3            4.5         1.5 versicolor
#>  68          5.8         2.7          4.1         1   versicolor
#>  69          6.2         2.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
#>  70          5.6         2.5          3.9         1.1 versicolor
#>  71          5.9         3.2          4.8         1.8 versicolor
#>  72          6.1         2.8          4           1.3 versicolor
#>  73          6.3         2.5          4.9         1.5 versicolor
#>  74          6.1         2.8          4.7         1.2 versicolor
#>  75          6.4         2.9          4.3         1.3 versicolor
#>  76          6.6         3            4.4         1.4 versicolor
#>  77          6.8         2.8          4.8         1.4 versicolor
#>  78          6.7         3            5           1.7 versicolor
#>  79          6           2.9          4.5         1.5 versicolor
#>  80          5.7         2.6          3.5         1   versicolor
#>  81          5.5         2.4          3.8         1.1 versicolor
#>  82          5.5         2.4          3.7         1   versicolor
#>  83          5.8         2.7          3.9         1.2 versicolor
#>  84          6           2.7          5.1         1.6 versicolor
#>  85          5.4         3            4.5         1.5 versicolor
#>  86          6           3.4          4.5         1.6 versicolor
#>  87          6.7         3.1          4.7         1.5 versicolor
#>  88          6.3         2.3          4.4         1.3 versicolor
#>  89          5.6         3            4.1         1.3 versicolor
#>  90          5.5         2.5          4           1.3 versicolor
#>  91          5.5         2.6          4.4         1.2 versicolor
#>  92          6.1         3            4.6         1.4 versicolor
#>  93          5.8         2.6          4           1.2 versicolor
#>  94          5           2.3          3.3         1   versicolor
#>  95          5.6         2.7          4.2         1.3 versicolor
#>  96          5.7         3            4.2         1.2 versicolor
#>  97          5.7         2.9          4.2         1.3 versicolor
#>  98          6.2         2.9          4.3         1.3 versicolor
#>  99          5.1         2.5          3           1.1 versicolor
#> 100          5.7         2.8          4.1         1.3 versicolor
#> 101          6.3         3.3          6           2.5 virginica 
#> 102          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica 
#> 103          7.1         3            5.9         2.1 virginica 
#> 104          6.3         2.9          5.6         1.8 virginica 
#> 105          6.5         3            5.8         2.2 virginica 
#> 106          7.6         3            6.6         2.1 virginica 
#> 107          4.9         2.5          4.5         1.7 virginica 
#> 108          7.3         2.9          6.3         1.8 virginica 
#> 109          6.7         2.5          5.8         1.8 virginica 
#> 110          7.2         3.6          6.1         2.5 virginica 
#> 111          6.5         3.2          5.1         2   virginica 
#> 112          6.4         2.7          5.3         1.9 virginica 
#> 113          6.8         3            5.5         2.1 virginica 
#> 114          5.7         2.5          5           2   virginica 
#> 115          5.8         2.8          5.1         2.4 virginica 
#> 116          6.4         3.2          5.3         2.3 virginica 
#> 117          6.5         3            5.5         1.8 virginica 
#> 118          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 virginica 
#> 119          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3 virginica 
#> 120          6           2.2          5           1.5 virginica 
#> 121          6.9         3.2          5.7         2.3 virginica 
#> 122          5.6         2.8          4.9         2   virginica 
#> 123          7.7         2.8          6.7         2   virginica 
#> 124          6.3         2.7          4.9         1.8 virginica 
#> 125          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.1 virginica 
#> 126          7.2         3.2          6           1.8 virginica 
#> 127          6.2         2.8          4.8         1.8 virginica 
#> 128          6.1         3            4.9         1.8 virginica 
#> 129          6.4         2.8          5.6         2.1 virginica 
#> 130          7.2         3            5.8         1.6 virginica 
#> 131          7.4         2.8          6.1         1.9 virginica 
#> 132          7.9         3.8          6.4         2   virginica 
#> 133          6.4         2.8          5.6         2.2 virginica 
#> 134          6.3         2.8          5.1         1.5 virginica 
#> 135          6.1         2.6          5.6         1.4 virginica 
#> 136          7.7         3            6.1         2.3 virginica 
#> 137          6.3         3.4          5.6         2.4 virginica 
#> 138          6.4         3.1          5.5         1.8 virginica 
#> 139          6           3            4.8         1.8 virginica 
#> 140          6.9         3.1          5.4         2.1 virginica 
#> 141          6.7         3.1          5.6         2.4 virginica 
#> 142          6.9         3.1          5.1         2.3 virginica 
#> 143          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica 
#> 144          6.8         3.2          5.9         2.3 virginica 
#> 145          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5 virginica 
#> 146          6.7         3            5.2         2.3 virginica 
#> 147          6.3         2.5          5           1.9 virginica 
#> 148          6.5         3            5.2         2   virginica 
#> 149          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica 
#> 150          5.9         3            5.1         1.8 virginica
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This doesn't seem to work for me though.  Only prints 31 rows from a tibble with hundreds. I don't have any unusual settings so it's strange if we get different results.